# ASP.Net Core/EF Method syntax: ignoring "orderby"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a C#/ASP.NET Core web app.  This particular page is using LINQ/Method syntax to query the database.  The query was working fine, but I'd like to return the results in sorted order.

Example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id, string myFilter="showActive")
{ 
   IQueryable<EFItem> myQuery;
    switch (myFilter)
    {
        case "showAll":
            myQuery = from i in _context.EFItems orderby i.CreatedDate select i;
            break;
        case "includeSales":
            myQuery = 
                from i in _context.EFItems 
                where i.CurrentStep != "NoOpportunity"
                orderby i.CreatedDate
                select i;
            break;
        default: // "showActive"
            myQuery =
                from i in _context.HCEXPItems
                where i.CurrentStep != "Completed"
                orderby i.CreatedDate
                select i;
        break;
    }
    EFItems = await myQuery.ToListAsync<EFItem>();
    return this.Page();
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be ignoring `orderby i.CreatedDate`.

What am I missing?  How can I specify "orderby" within the `myQuery` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand why you are getting an error, but can you try the following codes?

> _context.EFItems.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate);
>
> _context.EFItems.Where(x => x.CurrentStep != "NoOpportunity").OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate);

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  There was no "error". It just didn't show the sorted order. In retrospect, the problem was simply that that jQuery DataTables (in the browser)  was re-shuffling the table displayed in the browser (regardless of the order actually sent from the server). Whoops!  PS: LINQ has two "syntax flavors" - "Method Syntax" (my example above) and "Query Syntax" (yours): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Answer (score 0):

CAUSE:

I realized that my .cshtml page was displaying the data inside a *jQuery DataTable*.

The LINQ "orderby" (server side) was working fine ... but DataTable was changing the order on the client.

SOLUTION:

1. Delete"orderby" from the LINQ query
2. Specify an explicit sort order when initializing the DataTable:

   ```
    // Enable "Search"
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('MM/DD/YYYY');
    $('#indexTable').DataTable(
        order: [[3, 'desc']]
    );
   ```